# Finding work done for a chemical reaction at non-constant pressure and temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have studied the expression for work done for a chemical reaction which is basically $W=-\Delta n_{g}RT$. Along with this, the assumption that has been made is that chemical reactions take place at constant pressure and temperature.

*Is this always the case? What would the general expression for work done look like if we were to consider temperature and pressure changes during the chemical reaction?* Thanks.

Comment: Didn't your teacher derive that expression by starting with a general expression for work, and then applying the constraints that the only type of work is pV-work, and that the temperature are pressure are constant?

Comment: @theorist Yes it starts off with using $W=-P\mathrm dV$. So about the conditions I am asking in the OP, what would the starting point be for such a derivation?

Comment: Not quite. The starting expression for pV-work should be $\text{đ}w =  -p_{ext} dV$. Yes, you missed the differential, but the key point is that it's the external pressure that determines pV-work.  That expression does not require constant temperature or pressure.  Now what assumptions did your teacher add to go from that expression, to the one in your OP?

Comment: You have your answer.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

There are a series of five assumptions you need to make to get from the general expression for work, to the expression you wrote in your OP.  With each assumption, you are applying successively more constraints to your system.  In the post below I give the assumptions, and the equation that results from each, so that you can see how the form of the equation evolves as successively more constraints are applied.

We start with the general expression for work:

$$\text{đ}w = \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{x}$$

[We use the form $\text{đ}w$ rather than $dw$ because work is path-dependent, and its differential is thus inexact; the dyet glyph, $\text{đ}$, is used to indicate this.]

Now we integrate and express the dot product in terms of scalar quantities:

$$w = \int_{path} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{x} = \int_{path} |F| \,d |x| \cos(\theta)$$

Because work is path-dependent, it is necessary to integrate over the actual path, as indicated in the above integrals, rather than merely from the initial state to the final state.

Dropping the explict scalar notation, we can write it as:

$$w =  \int_{path} F d x \cos(\theta)$$

*Now let's add some assumptions:*

**Assumption 1: The force is applied in the direction of motion.**

As the angle between the direction of motion and the direction of force is $0$, and $\cos(0) = 1$, we have:

$$w =  \int_{path}F dx \cos(\theta) = \int_{path}F dx$$

**Assumption 2:  The work is $\bf{pV\text{– work.}}$**

For $pV\text{– work}$, we can take work done on the system to be either positive or negative.  I'll use the former convention. And we can only reliably use the external pressure to determine the work; the internal pressure is not always defined, particularly for rapid expansions or compressions.  To indicate this explicitly, we write "$p$" as $p_{ext}$. Then (using "$A$" for area):

$$p_{ext} = F/A;\,\,dV = -A dx\,\, \text{(negative sign is because as $x$ increases, $V$ decreases)}$$

$$\Rightarrow  \int_{path} F dx =  -\int_{path}(p_{ext}A) (dV/A) = -\int_{path}p_{ext} dV$$
Thus:

$$w = -\int_{path}p_{ext}dV$$

*This is the general expression for $pV\text{– work}$.  It applies regardless of the conditions.*

**Assumption 3: The system is in mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings.**
In this case, $p_{ext} = p_{sys}$.  By convention, we designate $p_{sys}$ simply as "$p$".

Note that this assumption restricts us to paths in which the system is continously in mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings.  This limits us to paths whose work depends only on the difference between the initial and the final state.  Thus we do not need to concern ourselves with doing an explicit path integral. I.e., because the path restriction is now implicit, we can simply integrate between intitial and final states (which I've designated as $i$ and $f$):

$$w =  -\int_{i}^{f}pdV$$

**Assumption 3a: The system is at constant pressure.**

Since $p$ is a constant, we can take it out of the integral:
$$w =  -\int_{i}^{f}pdV=  -p\int_{i}^{f}dV = -p\Delta V$$

I labeled this assumption as "3a" rather than 4 because we didn't need to both specify the system is at constant pressure and in mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings, since if it is at constant pressure it is also in mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings.

But I broke the steps up, since I wanted to give the expression following assumption 3 for completeness.

**Assumption 4: The system is an ideal gas.**

Substituting $V=nRT/p$, and remembering that the pressure is constant, gives:

$$w =  -p\int_{i}^{f}dV =  -p\int_{i}^{f}d(n R T/p)=-R\int_{i}^{f}d(n T)=-R\int_{i}^{f}ndT-R\int_{i}^{f}Tdn$$

**Assumption 5: The temperature is constant.**

Since $T$ is a constant, we can take it out of the integral:

$$w =-R\int_{i}^{f}d(n T)=-RT\int_{i}^{f}dn = -RT \Delta n$$

Or, equivalently:

$$w =-R\int_{i}^{f}ndT-R\int_{i}^{f}Tdn = -R\int_{i}^{f}Tdn = -RT\int_{i}^{f}dn = -RT \Delta n$$

Comment: About the dyet character, it is handy to define for it a user hot key combination in the MathJax editing script.

Comment: @Poutnik  How would I do that?  Right now MathJax doesn't recognize either of the commands that I know can make a dyet (\dj, which requires the fontec pkg, or \textcrd, which requires the tipa pkg)),so I have to just copy and paste it.

Comment: It is not  part of MathJax. The dyet 
unicode literal character would be inserted as a text string by invoking a hot key defined within the script. I use it on my desktop, writing this on phone. It is the same script that e.g. wraps a chemical formula by \$\ce{}\$ using CTRL+ALT+E. You can customize it.

Comment: See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4264/introducing-markdown-shortcuts-for-stack-exchange   You can define extra item using the dyet character e.g. instead of \pi string